# Cannot access action.payLoad.data from redux promise

Tags: react-redux, reduce

I am working on a weather app using redux promise, and having trouble retrieve `action.payLoad.data`.

`actions/index.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  //console.log("request:", request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payLoad: request
  };
}
```

`reducers/reducer_weather.js`

```js
import  { FETCH_WEATHER } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  if (action.type === FETCH_WEATHER) {
    console.log('Action.payLoad.data received:', action.payLoad.data);
    console.log('Action received:', action);
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      return [ action.payLoad.data, ...state ]; // return new instance of state array
  }
  return state;
}
```

No matter how I tried, any combination around `action.payload.data` returns `undefined`. How should I access the its value?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you using redux-promise middleware? if so, you should add **async/await**

Comment: Yes, I am using redux-promise middleware. Even without using async/await, I can access either action or action.payLoad, however, I can not access the action.payLoad.data, Because the action content is: Object.payLoad.[[PromiseValue]].data...as shown on the screenshot above.

Comment: The action content is: Object {type: "FETCH_WEATHER", payLoad: Promise}...as shown on the screenshot above. 
If the Object is in Object {type: "FETCH_WEATHER", payLoad: Object} format, I would be able to access action.payLoad.data successfully. So how to access payLoad: Promise?

Comment: The reason I have action Object {type: "FETCH_WEATHER", payLoad: Promise} instead of Object {type: "FETCH_WEATHER", payLoad: Object} is because ReduxPromise is looking for payload, not 'payLoad'.

Comment: Please suggest what exactly should be used, to retrieve the value of `action.payload.data`?

Comment: you should also ask Stephon on his course ;)

Comment: in my case, I had a typo at `payload` I had written that `paylaod` so it should be `o` before `a`

Answer (score 6):

Edit: I just saw the comment where you say you are using `redux-promise`. You should use `payload` in the return action, not `payLoad`. So your function would look like this:

```
function fetchWeatherPromise (city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  return {
      type: 'FETCH_WEATHER',
      payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.get(url).then(response => resolve(response.data))
      })
    } 
};
```

And your reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_WEATHER_PENDING':
        ...

    case 'FETCH_WEATHER_FULFILLED':
        return [action.payload, ...state];

    default:
        return state;
};
```

As this very good explanation on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/469iyc/help_performing_async_api_calls_with_reduxpromise/) says:

> First, some premises (in redux):
>
> - At the end of the redux lifecycle a new Store is returned from a reducer.
> - The new store that is returned is the end product of applying Actions to the previous store (using dispatch() !).
> - Actions should be SYNCHRONOUS in nature. The way I interpret this is that an action should be a plain object with plain data.
>
> So if we follow this line of thought we can think of actions as the information needed by a reducer to transform the current store into a new store (new state).
>
> I think, up to this point, you get that. So then how do you deal with api/xhr requests which are inherently asynchronous? You don't want to mix async functions with synchronous objects (actions) so then how is it possible to use api calls?
>
> This is where action creators come in.
>
> An Action Creator is simply a function that returns an action. Take note that this does NOT mean that an action creator has to dispatch the action it returns. All it does is return that synchronous, plain object, that we defined as an action.
>
> Knowing this we can speculate, "Hmm, well if it's just a function that returns an object, and it's not necessarily dispatching actions, then can action creators be asynchronous?"
>
> The answer to that question is yes!

What the action creator does is:

- It makes an async API call using a promise.
- It creates an object with the returned response (it might be the real data so you have to resolve your promise!).
- It dispatchs a sync action to the store with this object.

The promise middleware removes the need to write `myPromise.then()...` (resolve your promise) each time you want to make an async action. Instead of resolving the promises all the time, you just give it the information it needs to build the API call and the middleware will take care of the rest.

---

Old: You should reshape your function and add a [Middleware](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) to deal with async action creators. Also, `axios.get()` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and you should dispatch a sync action inside `then` so your reducer has access to the data fetched. Here is an example that how your action creator should look like using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

```
function fetchWeather(city) {
return (dispatch) => {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_WEATHER,
                payLoad: data
            });
        }) 
     }
}
```

Don't forget to add `applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)` to your store.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I do have mentioned that even using all-lowercase `... payload ...` doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you update your fetchWeather `function` ? You have to keep in mind that `axios.get()` returns a Promise and you need to resolve it to get the data. if you do `const request = axios.get(url);` and then `return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };` you are treating you code like synchronous code, which it isn't. If you return a promise on `payload`, `redux-promise` middleware will take care of that for you.

Comment: That way, when your promise is resolved, it fires a `FETCH_WEATHER_FULFILLED` action and you can update state there.

Comment: Hey @MohammadNaji, if you still don't understand, read this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/469iyc/help_performing_async_api_calls_with_reduxpromise/). It's really well explained there. LMK if I can help.

Comment: @MohammadNaji did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your index.js, make sure the ReduxPromise is wired in applyMiddleWare() call, like this

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to configure your redux-promise as middleware. You should just try to add redux-promise as middleware in your store configuration. refer below:

```
 import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
 import * as Counter from './Counter';
 import * as WeatherForecasts from './WeatherForecasts';
 import BooksReducer from '../reducers/reducer_books';
 import ActiveBook from '../reducers/reducer_active_book';
 import weatherReducer from '../reducers/weather';
 import Promise from 'redux-promise';


 export default function configureStore(history, initialState) 
 {
    const reducers = 
    {
        counter: Counter.reducer,
        weatherForecasts: WeatherForecasts.reducer,
        books: BooksReducer,
        activeBook: ActiveBook,
        weather: weatherReducer
    };

const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    Promise
];

// In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
const enhancers = [];
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) {
    enhancers.push(window.devToolsExtension());
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
});

return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same exact issue, the problem here is you did not apply the promise to your middleware in the base index.js you have. In your main index.js you need to include this line of code:

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in main index.js

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
```

in actions/index.js

```
export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);
  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payLoad: request
  };
}
```

in reducers/reducer_weather.js

```
import  { FETCH_WEATHER } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      return [ action.payLoad.data, ...state ]; 
  }
  return state;
}
```

Works fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  //console.log("request:", request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payLoad: request
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you go to your main index file (not the one in actions folder but one in the src folder)..and assure you have the following lines.

1. import ReduxPromise from
   'redux-promise';)
2. import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from
   'redux';
3. const createStoreWithMiddleware =
   applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
4. Add the folowing property to Provider tag =>
   ***store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}***

   Where reducers are coming from combined reducers file (./reducers).

Answer (score 0):

Open your index.js (root folder):

- Import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise',don't forget to install it first (npm install --save redux-promise)

```js
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
```

- add ReduxPromise to your applyMiddleware statement

```js
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
```

c. re-test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading the posts and answers, and everyone is right.. but it may be that you dont have ReduxPromise installed in your dependencies.. please check your package.json file to see, and then run or rerun "npm install redux-promise --save" .. that should fix the issue..

you should see the dependencies like this in your package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    **"redux-promise": "^0.6.0"**
```